# Query that will convert date into Month with count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table called Worked_Received.

Columns

```
Received Date  Ticket number
12/08/2014         2135823
13/09/2014         2458956
01/02/2014         2458796
03/07/2014         2456353
04/07/2014         2457896
```

I would like to have a result like this

```
Month      Count
August       1
September    1
February     1
July         2
```

Comment: What type is `Received Date`? Is it a `datetime` or a `varchar`? Also, are you asking about [tag:sql-server] or [tag:sqlite]? Surely it can't be both.

Comment: Hi @Mureinik, its sql server, and Varchar.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Count], 
    DATENAME(month,table1.[Received Date]) AS [Month]
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(month,table1.[Received Date])
```

**Update**

Some of the date can't be converted to a datetime. If you know that the varchar will always have the same format. You can use convert like this:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS [Count], 
    DATENAME(month,CONVERT(datetime,table1.[Received Date], 103)) AS [Month]
FROM
    table1
GROUP BY
    DATENAME(month,CONVERT(datetime,table1.[Received Date], 103))
```

**Update 2**

The dates that you have in the example data all casts without exception like this:

```
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES('12/08/2014'),('13/09/2014'),('01/02/2014'),
('03/07/2014'),
('04/07/2014')

SELECT
 DATENAME(month,CONVERT(datetime, tbl.date, 103))
FROM
@tbl AS tbl
```

The convertion error that you get is because there is a varchar that can't be converted to a date. To find out which row is not converting you can check this:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    table1
WHERE ISDATE(table1.[Received Date])=0
```

Reference:

- [DATENAME (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174395.aspx)
- [ISDATE (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187347.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Arion, it says Conversion Failed when converting date or time from character string

Comment: Conversion Failed when converting date and/or time from character string

Comment: Wow, 60% of the data cannot convert, what will be the next step?